# C# pressing key breaks movement of an object

Tags: c#, key, game-physics, keydown

I'm creating ping pong game. I managed to move both lines (picture box) at same time if keys for movement are pressed down. Problem is that if control for one player is pressed down and then other player JUST clicks (1 time) it breaks movement of other player,so that he needs to press key again. I tried to fix it with `keypress` and `Keyboard.IsKeyDown`but no luck.

Here is my code:

```
public void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Keys up1 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), form1.p5_text_kontrole_gor1.Text , true);
        Keys down1 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), form1.p5_text_kontrole_dol1.Text , true);

        Keys up2 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), form1.p5_text_kontrole_gor2.Text, true);
        Keys down2 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), form1.p5_text_kontrole_dol2.Text, true);

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            Application.Exit();

        if(e.KeyCode == up1)
        {
            goup1 = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == down1)
        {
            godown1 = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == up2)
        {
            goup2 = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == down2)
        {
            godown2 = true;
        }
        igra1();
    }

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Keys up1 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), form1.p5_text_kontrole_gor1.Text, true);
        Keys down1 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), form1.p5_text_kontrole_dol1.Text, true);

        Keys up2 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), form1.p5_text_kontrole_gor2.Text, true);
        Keys down2 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), form1.p5_text_kontrole_dol2.Text, true);

        if (e.KeyCode == up1)
        {
            goup1 = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == down1)
        {
            godown1 = false;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == up2)
        {
            goup2 = false;
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == down2)
        {
            godown2 = false;
        }
        igra1();
    }

public void igra1()
    {
        if (goup1)
        {
            if (form1.p6_ploscek1.Top > form1.panel6_pongIgra.Top)
                form1.p6_ploscek1.Top -= 15;
        }
        if (goup2)
        {
            if (form1.p6_ploscek2.Top > form1.panel6_pongIgra.Top)
                form1.p6_ploscek2.Top -= 15;
        }
        if (godown1)
        {
            if (form1.p6_ploscek1.Bottom < form1.panel6_pongIgra.Bottom)
                form1.p6_ploscek1.Top += 15;
        }
        if (godown2)
        {
            if (form1.p6_ploscek2.Bottom < form1.panel6_pongIgra.Bottom)
                form1.p6_ploscek2.Top += 15;
        }
    }
```

Comment: step thru the code to pinpoint where the exact issue and or error or problem is happening..that would be my first recommendation

Comment: Well error happens when I click button but I still don't get it how can it breaks movement of other player if his variable(goup2/godown2) is true

Comment: when you click what button.. also what method are you in when you state `Well error happens when I click button` also what line of code.. once again you need to step thru the code and but break points and report back on the exact line that it errors on..[Enum.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx)

Comment: Unable to reproduce with the limited information.  What happens in the button click code?

Comment: With button I meant keyboard button/control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're relying on the fact that keys get repeated by Windows while you hold them down to make your game pieces move.  The first key being held down will stop repeating because the new key being held down is repeating instead.

To fix this move the pieces in the Tick() event of a **Timer** control.  In the KeyDown/KeyUp events simply change the **state** of a variable that represents whether the associated piece should be moving (and what direction it should go).  The Timer code will look at the state variables and act accordingly...